# How can I enable activex controls on IE for auto loading of applets

Tags: java, python, internet-explorer, activex

I am working on some applets and whenever I'm trying to open the applets on IE using my python script, It stops for a manual input to enable the activex.
I tried doing it from the IE settings. but, I require a command line to do it by which I can integrate it in my python script only.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution to this.
We can make the below modification to the registry and achieve running of applets automatically without pop-ups

C:\Windows\system32>reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Feat
ureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN" /v iexplore.exe /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f